# manipulate structs in void functions

Tags: c, struct

I'm not very firm in using structs and currently trying to pass a struct through a void function.
The struct is defined in a shard header, as well as my void function:

```
/* "main.h" */

struct input{
    unsigned int NO;
    double RA;
    double DE;
    double MV;
};

void full_view_equ(struct input, struct input);
```

The function looks like this, it is nessecary to use two different structs. Struct EQU already contains values, OUTPUT will be uninitialized:

```
/* "transformations.c" */

#include "main.h"

void full_view_equ(struct input EQU, struct input OUTPUT){
    OUTPUT.NO = EQU.NO;
    OUTPUT.RA = -radian2degree(EQU.RA);
    OUTPUT.DE = radian2degree(EQU.DE);
    OUTPUT.MV = EQU.MV;
}
```

I'm calling the function with the two structs EQU and OUTPUT like this:

```
struct input EQU, OUTPUT;

full_view_equ(EQU, OUTPUT);
```

The problem is, that within the function, OUTPUT has the expected values. Outside the function, all entries of OUTPUT are zero instead.

I can't see what's wrong with it, before i was using arrays instead of structs and all was working fine.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function, structures don't. Pass pointers to the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a pointer to the structure and pass that to the function, in your code the OUTPUT struct in the function is actually a copy of the original one and changing the copy won't change the original one.
for declaring a pointer to a struct simply use this code:

```
struct input *OUTPUT;
```

and use this header for your function:

```
void full_view_equ(struct input EQU, struct *input OUTPUT)
```

and the call to the function would be:

```
full_view_equ(EQU, &OUTPUT);
```

Comment: And be sure to use "->" operator instead of the . operator. some IDEs will pass this but it's the standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments are passed by value. So you need to use pointers to modify value outside the function:

```
void full_view_equ(struct input EQU, struct input *OUTPUT){
    OUTPUT->NO = EQU.NO;
    OUTPUT->RA = -radian2degree(EQU.RA);
    OUTPUT->DE = radian2degree(EQU.DE);
    OUTPUT->MV = EQU.MV;
}
```

and call it like

```
full_view_equ(EQU, &OUTPUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a function with a struct parameter, you will be sending a *copy* of your struct to it. Once the function returns, that copy is lost.

You can either modify your function to return the struct, in which case you have to copy it back. Alternatively, you could modify your function to take a pointer to the structs.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing array to a function, it decays to pointers in function. Because array name represent the base address. But structures are not. So pass Pointer to the structure!

Instead of this-

```
full_view_equ(EQU, OUTPUT);
```

use-

```
full_view_equ(EQU, &OUTPUT); // pass a pointer to a structure
```

and catch it by structure pointer in function, replace `.` by `->` operator

```
void full_view_equ(struct input EQU, struct input *OUTPUT){
OUTPUT->NO = EQU.NO;
OUTPUT->RA = -radian2degree(EQU.RA);
OUTPUT->DE = radian2degree(EQU.DE);
OUTPUT->MV = EQU.MV;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing a variable to a function, a copy of this variable is made.

What you need here is to pass a pointer to your structure, then use

```
my_struct->data
```

instead of

```
my_struct.data
```

You will then pass a copy of the pointer to the function, but the pointed address will be your original struct, so you will be able to modify it :)

Answer (score 0):

Either pass a pointer to the struct...

```
void full_view_equ(struct input *EQU, struct input *OUTPUT){
    OUTPUT->NO = EQU->NO;
    OUTPUT->RA = -radian2degree(EQU->RA);
    OUTPUT->DE = radian2degree(EQU->DE);
    OUTPUT->MV = EQU->MV;
}

int main(void) {
    struct input a, b;
    memset(&b, 0, sizeof(b));
    full_view_equ(&a, &b)
}
```

Or return a struct from the function:

```
struct input full_view_equ(struct input EQU){
    struct input OUTPUT;
    OUTPUT.NO = EQU.NO;
    OUTPUT.RA = -radian2degree(EQU.RA);
    OUTPUT.DE = radian2degree(EQU.DE);
    OUTPUT.MV = EQU.MV;
    return OUTPUT;
}

int main(void) {
    struct input a, b;
    memset(&b, 0, sizeof(b));
    a = full_view_equ(b);
}
```

In theory, a copy of the struct would need to be made in the second case, but the compiler can optimize it away.

Comment: Is it `struct *input ` or `struct input *`? check it out!

Comment: Ouuups, didn't notice that! Thank you!